# Join few tables using IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iqueryable

Let's say I need to make a complicated query to database (it includes 4 tables). I've written 4 different methods that query 4 different tables and I know it's not good:

```
var groups = *method that contains of .Where(), .Select() etc, that queries groups*
var marks = *method that has a parameter GROUPS and queries another table*
...
```

So it's like a ladder: to query another table, I need the results of the previous query (that has another context :))

I know about the `Join` method, but how can I give it the results of previous query?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I can't see any of these 4 methods. Please add real code to your question

Comment: @Charlieface added!

Comment: if you are using the same context for all 4 queries EF can convert them into 1 request to db untill it is all `IQueryable`

Comment: @demo no, all these queries have 4 different contexts

Comment: Where is the code for this other table? And why do you have 4 different contexts?

Comment: @Charlieface I just added this as an example, 3 other queries looks almost the same. 4 contexts because it's a complex query and this is the only way to get data I need

Comment: Are the data in 4 different databases? Otherwise I don't understand your remark about needing 4 contexts

Comment: @grek40 it's the structure of the project, yes, it's DbContext, but when work with tables, you have to mention appContext.Animals

Comment: @Sam your last comment is not really clear to me... is it possible to access all tables from the same context or not (like `appContext.Animals, appContext.Breeds, ...` or `db1Context.Animals, db2Context.Breeds, ...`)? You need to provide more code and try to describe your structure in a way that won't be misunderstood by others.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but when it comes to joining multiple tables in one query, you can use model relationships (you can create them yourself or with the scaffold command, [here you have how to use it](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/existing-database) ), then you will be able to use a relation in a linq query.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).